# Verify token before push history to router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I believe this is a very simple question, but I am not accustomed to Async/callback world.

I made `PrivateRoute` in order to protect my resource from being shoot by unauthenticated user. If I check only `token` in the storage. It will normally push to resource. But it does not cover outdated `token`. Then I let it shoot to do verification with backend before proceed.

**Problem:**
`axios` call returns me corret value, but page does not push authenticated user to correct resource page
`console.log` shows me 1 `then` and stay in the login page

`App.js`

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthorized, ...otherProps}) => (
  <Route
    {...otherProps}
    render={props => (
      isAuthorized() ? (<Component {...props} />) :
        (
          <Redirect to={
            {
              pathname: '/',
              state: {from: props.location},
            }
          }
          />
        )
    )}
  />
);

function verifyToken(isAuthenticated){
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    axios.post(`${BACKEND_URL}/api-token-verify/`, {
      token: getAuthToken()
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log('then');
        return true;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('err');
        return false;
      });
  } else {
    console.log('ahaha');
    return false;
  }
}

// Deal with an ordinary outdated token. Hacked one will be handle on individual component
function hasToken() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
  const isAuthenticated = !((token === undefined) | (token === null));

  return verifyToken(isAuthenticated);
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Login}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/simulator/' isAuthorized={hasToken} component={Simulator}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Question:**
How can I let it run like sequential order?

**Answer:**
Thanks to `m0meni` his answer&comment solve my problem. Here is my solution base on his answer. I decided to put my solution here since in the future I might forgot it.
I make new `Component` and name it `Container`. Since I cannot put `redux` at this level.

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Container/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

`Container.js`

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Simulator from "../../simulators/components/Simulators";
import Login from "../../frontpage/components/login";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {CHECK_TOKEN} from "../../constants";

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthorized, ...otherProps}) => (
  <Route
    {...otherProps}
    render={props => (
      isAuthorized() ? (<Component {...props} />) :
        (
          <Redirect to={
            {
              pathname: '/',
              state: {from: props.location},
            }
          }
          />
        )
    )}
  />
);


// Deal with an ordinary outdated token. Hacked one will be handle on individual component
function hasToken() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
  return !((token === undefined) | (token === null));
}


class Container extends Component {
  /*
  * In order to do redux staff and not to mess up with top most <App/>
  * Container has been created to contain them all
  *
  * */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.validateToken();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const {isAuthenticated, wrapper} = this.props;
    console.log(typeof this.props.wrapper);
    if((typeof this.props.wrapper) === 'function') {
      console.log('this is function');
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Login}/>
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/simulator/' isAuthorized={this.props.wrapper} component={Simulator}/>
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </Fragment>
      )
    }else{
      console.log('wrapper is not a function');
      console.log(typeof this.props.wrapper);
      return null;
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({verifyTokenReducer}, ownProps) => {
  return verifyTokenReducer
};

const validateToken = () => {
  return {
    type: CHECK_TOKEN,
    payload: undefined
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {validateToken})(Container);
```

`reducers.js`

```
import {GOOD_TOKEN, INVALID_TOKEN} from "../constants";

function immediateReturnTrue(){
  return true;
}
function immediateReturnFalse(){
  return false;
}

export const VerifyTokenReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GOOD_TOKEN:
      return {
        isAuthenticated: true,
        wrapper: immediateReturnTrue
      };
    case INVALID_TOKEN:
      return {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        wrapper: immediateReturnFalse
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key insight here is that `verifyToken` will *never* return `true` because the if branch returns nothing, and the else branch returns `false`. The `return true` inside your promise is inside of the callback inside of `.then`, meaning that `return true` doesn't apply to the function `verifyToken`, but the anonymous function inside of `.then`.

In order to fix this, you need to return the promise from your `verifyToken` function, and handle it as a promise in the `PrivateRoute` component. Right now your render prop treats the promise as if it is an immediately available value rather than a promise. (you're not using `.then` anywhere)

```
render={props => (
  isAuthorized() ? (<Component {...props} />) :
    (
      <Redirect to={
        {
          pathname: '/',
          state: {from: props.location},
        }
      }
      />
    )
)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I am now trying to leave `PrivateRoute` as it be by adding intermediate function to handle `Promise`. Please let me know whether I am going to wrong way or not.

Comment: @Sarit you should have some component process the promise, and use `setState` to put into your React state whether or not you are authenticated. Then instead of `isAuthenticated` you use that state in your ternary.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved. I have to add one more `Component` like you have said that. The solution is very long to post here IMO. Then your precious comment should be fine for new comer.